# why these objects not collide when using the "intersects "

Tags: java

I make 2 objects(1. triangle (java.awt.polygon) and 2. rectangle(java.awt.rectangle)) and moved
these objects by TIMER . My aim is to make these 2 objects collide and bounce back each other.
The problem is Why they are not colliding and bounce, when i used the (..if(intersect..) part.
The compiler(cmd) encounter error saying ["no suitable method found for intersects(Polygon)"].

i feel weird because before this when i create 2 rectangle(use java.awt.Rectangle) and using the (..if(intersects)...)
it work perfectly. These 2 rect touch and bounced each other.
I need answer to this, what does the error mean ?Below is a part of the code Thank you.

```
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                    super.paintComponent(g);
        
                    //1
        
                    triangle1 = new Polygon(new int[]{x1, x2, x3},
                    new int[]{200, 100, 200}, 3);
                    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g2d.fill(triangle1);
        
                    //2
                    r1 = new Rectangle(x, 100, 200, 100);
                    g2d.setColor(Color. BLUE);
                    g2d.fill(r1);
       }
        
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if(x < 0 || x + r1.getWidth() > this.getWidth()) {
                        velx = -velx;
        
                    }
        
                     if(x1 < 0 || x3 > this.getWidth()) {
                        velx1 = -velx1;
                        velx3 = -velx3;
                        velx2 = -velx2;
            }
        
                    // below code not working
        
                     if(r1.intersects(triangle1)) {
                         velx = -velx;
        
                         velx1 = -velx1;
                         velx3 = -velx3;
                         velx2 = -velx2;
        
            }
            

            x += velx;
            x1 += velx1;
            x2 += velx2;
            x3 += velx3;
            repaint();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including more details on how this misbehaves.

Comment: Hmm, even if you "successfully collided and bounced 2 rectangle", what makes you think that the intersect (which you do not show) is able to handle triangles?

Comment: i dont know, maybe if they can be used to collide 2 rectangle maybe the(intersect) can be used to collide between rect and triangle.

Comment: Sorry im quite new here,  i want to post all the code here but the system prevent me from doing so, because it said "my questions contains mainly code", so i cut a part of it

Comment: how can i overcome this problem

Comment: By writing more non-code. Explain things, report on observations. Describe in details how it misbehaves. Oh, that's what I wrote in my first comment. What a coincidence.

Comment: On the other hand "post all the code here" is NOT what I asked for. Please study the concept of a [mre].

Comment: hahaha sorry my bad:). i explain the program i try to make.

1. i create a triangle(use java.awt.polygon) and a rectangle(use java.awt.Rectangle)
2. i use timer to make these objects move horizontally 
3. my aim is to make these 2 objects collide and bounce each other when they intersect by using the (..if(intersects)...).
4. but the compiler(cmd) encounter error saying  ["no suitable method found for intersects(Polygon)"] ,

Comment: 5. i feel weird because before this when i create 2 rectangle(use java.awt.Rectangle) 
  and using the (..if(intersects)...) it work perfectly. These 2 rect touch and bounced each other.

6. My question: i just want to know why the (..if(intersects)...) not working this time.

Comment: Are you aware that you can actually [edit] your post? The probably helpful information you provided in comments are rendered unreadable by the comments restrictions....

Comment: Now im aware of it. Haha sorry. Already edited. If anyone have any idea about this problem please share with me.

Comment: Please explain why the compiler error "no suitable method found for intersects(Polygon)" is not an answer for you? Funnily it sounds very much like "Why do you believe that `intersects()` (which is made for rectangles),  is able to handle triangles? (Polygons)".

Comment: I am by the way a little confused by the actual question you ask "Why they are not colliding and bounce...?" Because that one you seem to already have answered yourself. There is no colliding and bouncing because your program cannot be run at all. Which in turn is because of the error, which you are perfectly aware of.

Comment: thanks for the reply, well i dont know, maybe it has something to the with the "intersects" part . I do not change the code entirely and  i  ONLY  change the object that i created in paint component mthd . Nothing more.  From (Rectangle - Rectangle) to   (Triangle - Rectangle)  . The "intersects" part work fine with (Rectangle - Rectangle) meaning they collided and bounced. But not for (Triangle - Rectangle) . They moved and overlapped each other.

Comment: i want to know more  deeper why cmd gived me that reason for not able to compile it.

Comment: How can you observe that "(Triangle - Rectangle) . They moved and overlapped each other." AND "cmd ... not able to compile it." How do you run something which fails to compile? (java is not my core expertise, so maybe I am missing something obvious here)

Comment: sorry maybe i explain this wrongly from beginning , before i add the (..if(r1.intersects(triangle1)) part ,the (triangle -rectangle) move and overlapped each other because there is no "intersects" part and cmd have no problem in compiling it  .   But after i add the "intersects" part to make it bounce, the cmd cannot compile it.

Comment: why is it not working for(Triangle - Rectangle) but ok for(Rectangle - Rectangle)

Comment: And I'd really appreciate information on how you observe wrong behaviour of a program which gets compiler errors.

Comment: Just to clarify, is this the `intersects()` you have successfully used on Rectanlges? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html If not please provide a link to the description of the one you used. In my link there is one for four doubles, which obviously you did not use. The other expects a Rectangle2D as parameter. Again, I assume that is the one you used successfully for 2 rectangles. No `intersects()` is mentioned which takes a Polygon as parameter. So, at the risk of repeating myself, what makes you think that you can use it on a Polygon?

Comment: its ok Yunnosch, i already got the answer. Thank you very much.                                       https://coderanch.com/t/734926/java/triangle-rectangle-collision-noyt-happen

Comment: If you have a solution please create an answer here, in order to get this out of the list of unanswered questions. Also, I would be interested to know.